# How to move my divs "sideways" from one ul to another using sortable and/or draggable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to move my divs from my first ul to a container with two (or more really) ul:s. More or less I want to create a sort of artboard, in which I can place different coloured divs so to make a kind of pixel-art-piece. 
Now, this is the trial-code I have in order to understand how to do this, but of course it doesn't work... Here's the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4sats5oe/24/

And here's the code:

HTML

```
<div id="box">
<ul class="boxlist">
    <li class="line"><div></div></li>
    <li class="line"><div></div></li>
    <li class="line"><div></div></li>
</ul>
<ul class="boxlist">
    <li class="line"></li>
    <li class="line"></li>
    <li class="line"></li>
</ul>
</div>

<ul id="sortlist">
<li class="sort"><div class="small"></div></li>
<li class="sort"><div class="small"></div></li>
<li class="sort"><div class="small"></div></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#box {
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
border: 1px solid black;
}

.boxlist {
list-style-type: none;
float: left;
padding: 0px;
display: inline;
}

.line {
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
border: 1px solid black;
}

.small {
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
border: 1px solid black;
background-color: blue;
}

#sortlist {
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0px;
}
```

JS

```
 $(".boxlist").sortable({
cursor: "move",
placeholder: 'emptydiv'
});


 $(".sortlist").draggable({
 helper: "clone",
 revert: "invalid",
 connectToSortable: ".boxlist"
 });
```

Anybody know how to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a few things, for one your sortlist ul is an id, but you reference it as '.sortlist' instead of '#sortlist' in the jquery, so I fixed that, but it still didn't work. 
Then I added the original script tags from jQuery's draggable example page, and now things seem to be dragging properly. 
Finally I added

```
.sort {
    list-style-type: none;    
}
```

to keep the boxes from turning into lists when dragged. It still doesn't seem to have the desired effect, but I hope it gets you started:

```js
$(".boxlist").sortable({
    cursor: "move",
    placeholder: 'emptydiv'
}); 


$("#sortlist").draggable({
     helper: "clone",
     revert: "invalid",
     connectToSortable: ".boxlist"
});
```

```css
#box {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.sort {
    list-style-type: none;    
}

.boxlist {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px;
    display: inline;
}

.line {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.small {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: blue;
}
#sortlist {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="box">
    <ul class="boxlist">
        <li class="line"><div></div></li>
        <li class="line"><div></div></li>
        <li class="line"><div></div></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="boxlist">
        <li class="line"></li>
        <li class="line"></li>
        <li class="line"></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<ul id="sortlist">
    <li class="sort"><div class="small"></div></li>
    <li class="sort"><div class="small"></div></li>
    <li class="sort"><div class="small"></div></li>
</ul>
```